# Can I make every class names with hash or random string?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm a new for styled-components.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TitleSection>
        <p className='title'>Hello CodeSandbox</p>
        <DescriptionSection>
          <p className='title'>Start editing to see some magic happen!</p>
        </DescriptionSection>
      </TitleSection>
    </div>
  );
}

const TitleSection = styled.div`
  .title {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: red;
  }
`

const DescriptionSection = styled.div`
  .title {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
`
```

[image]

I have a problem to use it. I want to show `DescriptionSection` title colored default(black).

Both styled-components have `.title` style using hash class name.

Is it possible to make hashed class name `.title` ?

I know some way to solve this problem, using `& > .title` and make `Title` styled-components.

But I want to know other way to solve this problem without using above way.

Comment: import external stylesheet with .title {color:#000)\}

Comment: @arvindpundir showing same result

Comment: check this https://blog.jayway.com/2019/05/02/how-to-override-styled-components-styling-with-external-css/

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code , " Button is default " and TomatoButton is child with changed style (override).

```
// The Button from the last section without the interpolations
const Button = styled.button`
color: palevioletred;
font-size: 1em;
margin: 1em;
padding: 0.25em 1em;
border: 2px solid palevioletred;
border-radius: 3px;`;
// A new component based on Button, but with some override styles
const TomatoButton = styled(Button)`
color: tomato;
border-color: tomato;`;
render(
<div>
<Button>Normal Button</Button>
<TomatoButton>Tomato Button</TomatoButton>
</div>);
```